# My PC becomes slow for 2-3 minutes after launching a program

Tags: windows-10

A few days ago I attempted to launch a program called 'Nexon Launcher' and I was stuck at an infinite loading screen. But what was strange was that I wasn't able to do a lot of things. I couldn't open my Task Manager to close the program, I couldn't use my web browser, and everything felt like it was slowing down(?) except I could still use Discord to chat with people in my call, but not sure if I could do anything else. I attempted to restart my PC through the Windows menu and it didn't manage to restart, so I forcefully shut down my PC with the button. I got a blue screen of death, but it fixed itself. For some reason the Nexon Launcher updated, but still took a long time to load and I was able to play the game I wanted, but today, I can't manage to get it to open again. So I decided to just stop playing the game until I figure out what to do. Today, I attempted to play a game of League of Legends and after selecting a champion, I get stuck for about 2-3 minutes with me not being able to do anything. If I attempt to open Task Manager, nothing. After 2-3 minutes, it opens up and that's when I know I'm finally in the loading screen. Mozilla Firefox becomes unresponsive as well. I don't know what to do at all. This is a new issue and my PC is just about new.

**Operating System**: Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.2604)

Here are my specs:

**CPU**: Intel Core i7-8700k 3.7 GHz 6-Core Processor
**CPU Cooler**: Corsair H100i v2 70.69 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler

**Motherboard**: Asus Prime Z370-A ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
**Memory**: CORSAIR Vengeance RGB PRO 64GB DDR4 3600

**Storage**: Samsung 970 Evo 250 GB M.2-2280

**Storage 2**: Samsung 860 Evo 500 GB SSD
**Storage 3**: Toshiba P300 3 TB 7200 RPM

**Storage 4**: Samsung 980 Pro SSD 2 TB

**GPU**: EVGA GeForce RTX 3090 FTW3 Ultra Gaming, 24GB GDDR6X

**PSU**: EVGA SuperNOVA 850 W 80+ Gold Certified

**BIOS Version**: 1601

When the problem occurs, I usually have Discord and Mozilla Firefox running when the problem occurs.

I don't really come across any errors at all, so I don't really have any error messages to show you.

The only troubleshooting I've really gone through is virus scans, chkdsk and disk defrag.
Sorry for the long post, I really tried to keep it brief!

Comment: uninstall 'Nexon Launcher'?

Comment: @DavidPostill I've already uninstalled that program. It wasn't an issue before and it only started to happen recently.

Comment: Rrun dism /sfc  :   Admin Command Prompt:  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  followed by sfc /scannow and restart, test

Comment: @John I just ran those commands and attempted to load into a game of League of Legends. I'm getting the same issue

Comment: Run a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Everything.  See if that works

Comment: Also check for malware. Not only with the existing anti-malware suite, e.g., Windows Defender, but with an additional scanner, e.g., https://www.lifewire.com/free-on-demand-virus-scanners-1356635

Comment: Hey John, I just attempted to reinstall a new Windows 10, because I didn't know how to repair it. But I was able to still keep my stuff. Seems like it didn't work

@DrMoishePippik I used Bitdefender to scan for malware, but it didn't find anything.

Comment: What antivirus product(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running into a similar issue with League of Legends. I've got the same RAM, OS, same SSD, and a gtx 1060 6gb gpu. I've reinstalled League on different SSDs and tried different RAM sticks only to find the same issue persists. After reinstalling Windows and testing again, the issue stopped!

I also got some feedback from Riot Support on my end and they're saying it could be related to BitDefender, I was able to confirm this is the underlying issue. It doesn't seem to be base bitdefender, but perhaps the most recent update? I'd try uninstalling that to confirm. You can also try to just disable the Advanced Threat Protection and see if that resolves it for you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to be helpful. This is really just the question "are you using BitDefender as your security software?", and not really a full answer. As such I have added this question to the main post as a comment.

Comment: They mentioned they were using BitDefender to scan for malware, and I lack the karma to comment on the post. I contacted Riot Support with this issue and successfully resolved it after disabling Advanced Threat Protection from BitDefender.

Comment: I understand that not having privileges yet can be frustrating when you feel you have something to add. It is not difficult to earn that privilege though, but not by disregarding the rules. Please read the help section and learn how you can contribute positively to this site and begin earning the privileges here.